# SEO impact of converting a small site to a single page with scrollable sections

Tags: seo, redirects, single-page-application

I have to redesign a website that has many sections with different URLs: Home, Contact, Services, Who are we?, etc.

I want to put them all into just one scrollable index page, with a menu in which I could slide smoothly to the section I want (like most of the new company websites).

The problem is that I read that if I am going to stop using some URLs, I have to keep the file but redirecting them to the page where I moved the information in with protocol 301. So in this case I am guessing that I have to redirect all the pages to only one page.

Is that how it’s supposed to be done? I feel like it might hurt the positioning in Google to have only one actual page and the others redirecting to it. What else do I have to keep in mind with this kind of changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deal with this in many ways.

**Method 1:**
You can design long home page with the original home page content, minimum info about: about us, services, contact us with a link to their dedicated page. By doing this you can achieve long scrolling page and you can maintain dedicated pages and ranking.

**Method 2:**
You can design long home page with the home page content and other pages which might not have much ranking like: about, contact etc. And you can leave dedicated pages for those URLs where you had the ranking like: services (Assuming you had ranking).

**Redirection 301:**
You should be fine to redirect general pages to the home page. It may not be recommended to redirect those pages which might have significant ranking unless you plan to address differently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!. I don't understeand Method 1. You mean that I put all the information in the index page, but still keep all the information in the other pages as I had it before? would't this be redundant and penalized by google?

Comment: What i meant in method 1 is, you can have minimum info in home page with the graphic. For example, let's say in home page you got a section for About Us and you can have the heading: Who are we with 2 - 3 lines of text and few bullet points and you can place a link / button, Learn More and it can take user to the dedicated page of About Us where you can discuss in detail possibly not repeating same content or even if you need to you can paraphrase it.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use anchors.

On your page you place an anchor something like this `<div><a id="example"></a>Our About Us Page</div>` the anchor will be invisible on the page.

A link to it looks like `<a href="index.php#about">About Us</a>` or if jumping within a page just `<a href="#about">About Us</a>`

Comment: and the downvote was because...

Comment: Because it doesn't address the question correctly it terms of ranking impact, redirection etc. It's more like how it could be done. Also, with anchor link, you may not want to have it on index.php as mostly it will be set to redirect to /.

Comment: "Is that how it´s supposed to be done?" this answer is one way to do it.  Your results may vary.

Comment: As stated, the answer is about how to do anchor text and not about 301, redirecting other pages to home page and impact on ranking. I have changed the vote, you might need to amend the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that wasn´t the issue I was asking about.

Comment: It looks like he already knows how to do it, but wants to know what the impact will be for Google rankings.